# JQuery AJAX Post Request keeps failing with absolute URL

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to test an API via AJAX. I have used JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#ajax').click(function(e){

        var sampleHTML = '<html></html>';

        var api_key = 'asfasasfs2';        

        $.post('http://google.com/', { api_key: api_key, html: sampleHTML },

           function(data) {

             alert("Data Loaded: " + data);

        });

    });

});
```

When ever I use an absolute URL, which I need to as this is an external API, firebug shows me nothing. As if no post request was made!

I thought I would test it on chrome and it shows the status as cancelled and the type as pending. What does this mean?

Please note, I've put Google's URL to hide my API URL.

Comment: where is this API? Is it on/under the same domain as the javascript that's calling it?

Comment: Make sure to check your firebug settings, this works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/FsWjF/

Comment: @Alastair - It is an external API on a completely different domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). If the url is not on the same domain, it won't work:

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

You could try an [ajax post with script or jsonp as the return data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if you can adjust your api:

> Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions.

Comment: I tried setting my AJAX request as `jsonp` but it keeps showing up as a GET request even though I am using exactly the same as above.

Comment: JSONP needs to be supported on the API side, you can't just use it when required.

Comment: @Alastair - it is supported. Even if it wasn't, Chrome shouldn't show the request as a GET request unless that's the only way you can use it as a GET request?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#ajax').live("click", function(e){


            $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://www.google.com",
                        data:   "api_key"="asfasasfs2"
                            "&html="<html><html>", 
                        success: function(html){
                            alert(data);
                        },
                         error: function(request){
alert(request.responseText);
                          },
                            complete    : function(){
                            }
                        });
    });

});
```

Try this. it should work. and the same-origin policy does not apply to forms being posted.
if the fire bug doesn't show anything that means the click event is not generated

Comment: Actually, same origin policy does affect ajax post. Only way around is with script or jsonp as return data. See ['Additional Notes' in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Yeh, this gets cancelled. So I think its effected by the same origin policy.